# having issue in Deserialize data in future callout methods and after again serialize that data

Tags: json

I am having issue in serializing the data.

```js
{
    "currency": "",
    "fields": [
        {
            "key": "Number",
            "value": "56"
        },
        {
            "key": "tranNumber",
            "value": "null"
        },
        {
            "key": "accNumber",
            "value": "1765975"
        }
    ],
    "country": "India"
}
```

Here I am deseralizing this above data in future callout method and passing the data to next method and in that next method I am again serializing that data to send it to rest call, but after serializing I am geeting different data as below

```js
{
    "fields": [
        {
            "value": "56",
            "key": "Number"
        },
        {
            "value": "null",
            "key": "tranNumber"
        },
        {
            "value": "11165975",
            "key": "accNumber"
        }
    ],
    "currency": null,
    "country": "India"
}
```

So here key and value getting in reverse so getting 400 error.
my wrapper class for deseralization is:

```java
public class Fields {
    public String key {get;set;} 
    public String value {get;set;} 
}  

public class data {
    public String currency {get;set;} 
    public List<Fields> fields {get;set;} 
    public String country {get;set;} 
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The ordering of the key values in JSON normally does not matter - see e.g. [Introducing JSON](https://www.json.org/json-en.html) - and the Apex implementation of deserialization/serialization in the [JSON Class](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexref.meta/apexref/apex_class_System_Json.htm) does not preserve any pre-excisting order.

I would be surprised if the service that is returning the 400 error is doing so because of the ordering of the names. A more likely cause of the error is:

```
"currency": null,
```

so track down why that is happening.